# RegExp group for xml elements

Tags: xml, regex

How can I get observation element and its inner elements?

```
 <organizer moodCode="EVN" classCode="CLUSTER">
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.6.0"/>
    <statusCode code="completed"/>
    <component>
       <observation moodCode="EVN" classCode="OBS">
          <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.6.1"/>
          <code codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Kabul Bilgileri" codeSystemName="Veri Kısmı" code="KABUL_BILGILERI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.3"/>
          <effectiveTime value="20120102134751"/>
          <value xsi:type="CD" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Diğer" codeSystemName="Kabul Şekli" code="98" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.7"/>
       </observation>
    </component>
    <component>
       <observation moodCode="EVN" classCode="OBS">
          <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.4.365"/>
          <code codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Vaka Türü" codeSystemName="Veri Elemanı" code="VAKA_TURU" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.7"/>
          <value xsi:type="CD" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Normal" codeSystemName="Vaka Türü" code="1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.53"/>
       </observation>
    </component>
 </organizer>
```

UPDATE:
This could be html or another markup language. I just want to retrieve observation elements and inner elements. I won't use this in a program when it is running.

Comment: [By using an XML parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Don't use regex, use parsers!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/647772

Comment: regex? What language are you using? Why to you need to get observation? Is the XML you have a string or some other object (XElemenet, XmlDocument, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

[As Jeff explained](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), you should definitely avoid using regular expressions for that job, when XML parsers exist and would take care of all the nasty details for you!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others you need an XML parse *not* regular expressions.

Use your XML parser's<sup>1</sup> XPath selection with the query:

```
//observation
```

to get all the `<observation>` elements with their child nodes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Without knowing you programming platform we cannot help you with that part.